# Indexing Arabic PDF Files using Solr

Tags: pdf, solr, document, apache-tika

I'm trying to search text documents using Solr and Tika. Everything works fine for .docx,.pptx,.csv,.xlsx,.. but when it comes to .pdf files, it returns empty content. I can't figure out where the problem is!

Comment: How you are indexing ?

Comment: I used the ExtractRequestHandler in the solrconfig file, and then I used curl command to index the pdf file. It gets all the correct metadata, but the content is like this: attr_filecontent":[" \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n "]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using post.jar to index files Use -Dauto

Example :

```
java -Dauto -Dc=collection_name -jar post.jar pdf_file.pdf
```

Using -Dauto we can index all document format that tika supports.
i.e txt,doc,docx,pdf,xml,html etc.

add these arabic filter class to field definition

```
<fieldType name="text_general_arabic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="arabic_stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>    
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="arabic_stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>    
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get the same result with pdf files.

Comment: forgot to inform, you need to include arabic filters in your schema file for field definition

Comment: I included the arabic filters in the schema file. I have the same issue even with english pdf files!

Comment: I get no errors when indexing. All data is available except the content.

Comment: According to another post it's maybe because the file is opened in a non-binary mode. Do you have any idea on how to do it in binary mode ?

Comment: Nope. I modified answer. included some arabic filter class did try those filters.

Comment: It didn't work ! I really can't figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to correctly parse PDF's, as PDF can contain inside text or images. We created a tool to easily search throught the content of any file.
Based on our experience:

1. Parse PDF with PDFbox first
2. If step 1 return zero -> do an OCR

The full description of process you can find in our blog https://blog.ambar.cloud/ingest-attachment-plugin-for-elasticsearch-should-you-use-it/

Hope it helps.

*P.s. our integrated solution https://github.com/RD17/ambar*